# How do char pointers work if the read only memory they point to is not sequential?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I've read that strings are sequential characters that are terminated by a nul terminating byte.

This makes sense and is the case when generating a string from an array of chars (`char test[] = "test";`)
(each character is one byte after the previous character in memory when printing `&test[i];`)

When I do the same using a pointer (`char *test = "test"`) I get non sequential memory addresses.

When printing the dereferenced pointer, how does it work out what order the characters are in if they are not in the correct order in memory? (And how does it know where the NULL termination character is?)

**Edit: Looks like I'm making up something that didn't happen. Can't reproduce what I was doing so I obviously got myself confused. Thanks for the help!**

Comment: What makes you think it's non-sequential?

Comment: When I print out the address of each character in the pointer it isn't sequential - for example in 'test' the address for the two 't' characers  are the same at the start and end of the word

Comment: Can you show how you're checking the addresses of the two 't's?  There's probably something not right about it... the characters should be in sequence as with the array.

Comment: @Joel: test and test+3 should be different addresses!

Comment: You really need to show your code because what you describe is not remotely what experienced C programmers would expect.  Please see how to construct an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I do the same using a pointer (char *test = "test") I get non sequential memory addresses.

This is not correct. What happens in this case is that a **string literal** is assigned to the pointer `*test`. This is typically in the ROM and at a different location than the RAM.

So, `*test` will be a different value, say 0x12345. Then we can say the following,

Address 0x12345 will hold character 't'.

Address 0x12346 will hold character 'e' and therefore

Address 0x12349 will hold character '\0'

The string will be sequential, and the null character will be at the last location.

Comment: "test" is not in the ROM, but at a different section in the process address space called .rodata (in case of ELF).

Comment: @tapananand Don't think so. The immediate value "test" is not a const data and should be located at the code section.

Comment: @Holsety: "test" is a const data, try this: *test = "g".

Comment: @tapananand You are assigning a string literal to a `char` there...

Comment: @CoolGuy: Yeah!! I messed up!

Comment: @Holsety: Sorry, I wrote the wrong thing. Try this: *test = 'g';
You will get segmentation fault because we are trying to write to the .rodata section of the address space.

Comment: @tapananand I have no environment to test it immediately. But I searched some articles, and know that although the storage location is depended on the implement,  you are right with the case for ELF. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 2):

The "non-sequential" means the difference between an initialized character *array* and an initialized character *pointer*.

Here's a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char testary[] = "abc";
char *testptr = "abc";

void
show(const char *sym,char *str)
{

    for (;  *str != 0;  ++str)
        printf("%s %p --> '%c'\n",sym,str,*str);
}

int
main(void)
{

    printf("\n");
    printf("testary=%p\n",&testary);
    show("testary",testary);

    printf("\n");
    printf("testptr=%p\n",&testptr);
    show("testptr",testptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the partial output of `nm` for the program on my system:

```
0000000000601040 D testary
0000000000601048 D testptr
```

Here's the program output:

```
testary=0x601040
testary 0x601040 --> 'a'
testary 0x601041 --> 'b'
testary 0x601042 --> 'c'

testptr=0x601048
testptr 0x4006d0 --> 'a'
testptr 0x4006d1 --> 'b'
testptr 0x4006d2 --> 'c'
```

When the linker fills in `testary`, it is putting the character string in the array itself (i.e. the string data is physically stored at that location). When it fills in `testptr`, it is putting the character string at some location of its choosing and filling the pointer with that address value.

After that, things are accessed the same because the compiler generates slightly different code to start the two cases for the `show` call.

In this case, the address of the "string literal" is `0x4006d2`, which is where the string data is physically stored